# Can any one help in removing validation error

Tags: html, xhtml

can any body Help me in this

```
    2   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN"
    3     "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
    4   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0" dir="ltr"
    5     xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    6     xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
    7     xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
    8     xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
    9     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    10     xmlns:sioc="http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#"
    11     xmlns:sioct="http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#"
    12     xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
    14
    15   <head profile="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab">
    16     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

This is html for my website after doing validation it is showing message

xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
                ^

Error: there is no attribute xmlns:content for this element (in this HTML version)

this message is showing for line 5 to line 13,I am not getting it 
 any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0" dir="ltr"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
    xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
    xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:sioc="http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#"
    xmlns:sioct="http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#"
    xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#" >
```

Please close this html tag  with closing angular brace at line no 12

Please close this  and try.
I guess U forgot to close " > " for html

Answer (score 0):

Either:

1. Use a DTD which includes `xmlns:content` and the other attributes you wish to use *or*
2. Remove the attributes that the validator reports as not existing in the DTD you are validating against